# Ionic - Android build fails while iOS works

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Trying to build my ionic app for android but it fails with:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

but it fails with:

```
Cannot determine the module for class OverlayPortal in
~/app/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/overlay-portal.d.ts! Add
OverlayPortal to the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the modulefor class IonicApp in
~/app/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/app-root.d.ts! Add IonicApp to
the NgModule to fix it. Cannot determine the module for class ClickBlock in
~/app/node_modules/ionic-angular/umd/components/app/click-block.d.ts! Add ClickBlock
to the NgModule to fix it.
```

Building for iOS works like a charm. Any ideas how to approach this? I already removed and added android back, still the error...
It's a default package, nothing I installed myself.

```
ionic --version
3.20.0
```

I did not dare upgrade to 4.5 since running on OSX Mojave and the build bug. Could the old be it?

```
ionic info

? The Ionic CLI has an update available (3.20.0 => 4.5.0)! Would you like to install it? No
Not automatically updating your CLI.

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.1 (cordova-lib@8.1.0)

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.4 ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 2.0.0
    Node       : v8.11.2
    npm        : 5.6.0
    OS         : macOS
    Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro


JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I have Android SDK 9, 8.1, 7.1.1, 6 installed

Comment: Could you share the output of ionic info ?

Comment: @DelwynPinto Done

Comment: This helps. Seems something specific to android. Is there a code or plugin that is platform specific / platform dependent ? Also, which android sdk are you using ?

Comment: How do I find out? I am treating Android as a necessary evil so I do not have much experience with it other than building the app...

Comment: You will find the SDK at the location it was installed in. Usually its <Program files>\Android\Android-sdk\platforms\<platform SDK's>. Else, if you have Android Studio installed, you can check within its SDK Manager. 

For plugins, you will have to check each individual one to be sure.